# sum some specific variables value in r

Tags: r, tidyverse

I select some specific variables using `grep()` to do some other calculations that failed. **I then created a new variable consisting of  variables name and "+", not sum of the value.**

```
# create a df
test <- data.frame(I60_freq_t = 1,
                   I60_freq_man = 1,
                   I60_freq_woman = 1,
                   I60_freq_lo65 = 1,
                   I60_freq_hi65 = 1,
                   I61_freq_t = 1,
                   I61_freq_man = 1,
                   I61_freq_woman = 1,
                   I61_freq_lo65 = 1,
                   I61_freq_hi65 = 1,
                   I62_freq_t = 1,
                   I62_freq_man = 1,
                   I62_freq_woman = 1,
                   I62_freq_lo65 = 1,
                   I62_freq_hi65 = 1
                   )

# extract variables with different end words and use " + " to concatenate
end_with_t <- grep('t$', names(test), value = T) %>% paste(collapse = '+')
end_with_man <- grep('[^a-z]man$', names(test), value = T) %>% paste(collapse = '+')
end_with_woman <- grep('woman$', names(test), value = T) %>% paste(collapse = '+')
end_with_lo65 <- grep('lo65$', names(test), value = T) %>% paste(collapse = '+')
end_with_hi65 <- grep('hi65$', names(test), value = T) %>% paste(collapse = '+')

# sum the value 
test2 <- test %>% mutate(t = end_with_t,
                         man = end_with_man,
                         woman = end_with_woman,
                         lo65 = end_with_lo65,
                         hi65 = end_with_hi65) 
# **** What I want is sum the value not sum the variables names *********
```

My questions are:

1.How can I revise my code to get what I want?

2.Are there  better ways to do this?

Any help will be highly appreciated!!!

Comment: Take a look at `mutate_at` and use `contains/ends/starts_with` or write a function and map it to your data. What is your expected output, does collapse really sum?

Comment: @NelsonGon, no `paste` with `collapse = "+"` just creates strings with a plus character `"+"` between elements.

Comment: @NelsonGon， I want to sum the value. For example , new variable should like this `t = 3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one idea using `map_dfc` to loop through the variable names and add them all together using `rowSums`. `ends_with` is a way to select the variables based on the end of a string.

```
library(tidyverse)

variables <- c("_t", "_man", "_woman", "_lo65", "_hi65")

test2 <- map_dfc(variables, ~test %>% 
          select(ends_with(.x)) %>%
          rowSums()) %>%
  setNames(str_remove(variables, fixed("_")))

test2
# A tibble: 1 x 5
      t   man woman  lo65  hi65
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     3     3     3     3
```